# Where to put an arithmetic checked statement?

Tags: c#, performance, math, overflowexception

I'm reading about how to force an operation to throw an overflow exception, and on the "try it yourself" section, I had it in a different place than the book. I'm curious if there's a performance issue associated with one spot or the other, as I'm not certain the underlying mechanics of the `checked` keyword.

The example in the book was doing a factorial, which will quickly throw an overflow, even with an unsigned long. This is the code that I came up with:

```
static long Factorial (long number) {
    long result = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
        checked {
            result *= i;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, looking at the answer page in the back of the book, they had the `checked` wrapped around the entire body of the function, including the `return` and `long result = 1;`. Obviously you'll never need one in those places, so if anything, I would just wrap the `for` loop in the `check`.

Is the presence of it inside the loop causing some underlying CLR code to be generated repeatedly? (Like why you declare a variable before entering a for loop.) Or is there no overhead having it inside the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is going to be little difference in terms of the compiled results.

The main difference is that any arithmetic operation within the `checked` block will use a different IL instruction.  There aren't *more* instructions, just different ones.  Instead of [`mul`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.mul%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you get [`mul.ovf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.mul_ovf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - instead of [`add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you get [`add.ovf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.add_ovf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), etc.

Your version actually has slightly different behavior, however.  Since you're putting the `checked` block in the tigher scope, the variable increment (`i++`) will still be unchecked.  The original would have been checked all the way through, which means that the `i++` could throw, not just the multiplication operation.  This does mean your version is faster, but only because you're avoiding the overflow checks and changing the resulting behavior, not because of the scope change.

> Is the presence of it inside the loop causing some underlying CLR code to be generated repeatedly?

No, it just means those IL instructions inside of that scope will get the different IL operation codes with overflow checks instead of the standard ones.

> Or is there no overhead having it inside the loop?

There is no overhead (other than the extra overhead of the checks in the instructions itself).

Comment: That's actually a very good overall catch with my code. If the parameter is greater than int32.MaxValue, then I'm going to overflow on that as well.

Comment: @krillgar Yes - I edited to include more links to details, etc.  Basically, it just changes how the compiler makes the instructions in those spots, but doesn't actually add extra IL opcodes.

Comment: Thanks, the extra details really help understand what's going on.